# How to Filter WHERE Field Value LIKE any of the values stored in a Multi Value Parameter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report (built using SSRS) that uses a multi-value parameter.

I want to add a Filter onto my SQL Query WHERE FieldA is LIKE any of the values stored in the parameter.

So `FieldA` might have the following values:

```
BOBJAMESLOUISE  
MARYBOB  
JENNY  
JOHNLOUISEJAMES  
BOB  
JENNYJAMESMIKE
```

And @`ParamA` might have the following values:

```
Bob, Louise
```

Therefore in this example only records `1, 3, 4 and 5` should be returned

Thanks to any help in advance :)

P.S I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You will want to implement a function like the split function.  This can take a comma separated value list and separate it into rows like you want.

Below is a link for a couple of different versions, any of them will work for you.  It also tells you how to use it.

[Split Function](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing its not the spiting sting part that is the issue since just googling for SQL split string you can find a lot of example. In your case what you would want after the split string is something like this. Assuming that the split string function you end up using returns a table of values Here is what your comparison query for with field A would look like.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM YourTableWithFieldA WHERE (@ParamA IS NULL OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM        YourSplitFunctionThatReturnsATableOfValues(@ParamA) SplitTable WHERE (FieldA Like '%'+SplitTable.Value+'%')))
> ```